# How do I increase the size of the devices under the Preview(Main Storyboards)?

Tags: ios, xcode8

I designed a screen and wanted to preview in Preview(Main Storyboard). It was displaying fine but suddenly it decreased in size. I don't know how to fix it. Whatever device I am chosen, it is showing in very small size. [This is the screen which I am seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCSYg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double click on white space in preview.Hope this may help you

Comment: Thank you. You saved my day. 
Even though it asked me to avoid commenting "Thanks" or "+1" but thank you anyway!!